# how can I fix Cannot read property 'error' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I fetch Data and want to output the data. It Works but I also want to make a error handling.

Like:

```
const func = async data => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch('MY_URL);
    const out = await res.json();

    if(out) {

      const name = out.result.name;

      if(out.result.error) {
        console.log('ERROR');
      }

    }
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

Why I get this message?

```
Cannot read property 'error' of undefined
```

Ok, I dont have an object with error, but I want to say If there is an error object, then I want to show anything else.

How I fix it?

EDIT:

```
                // Error Handling Statuscode
                if (out.result[0].statuscode.error) {
                    allCircle[0].innerHTML = errorIcon;
                    domainInfo[0].innerText = out.result[0].statuscode.error;
                }
```

I dont have statuscode.error. But If an Error in my system happens, then I get the property error. So how can I say If error exists? Because error property doesnt always exists.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```js
if(out.result && out.result.error) {
  console.log('ERROR');
}
```

That way you would shortcut the evaluation of the `error` property if there is no `result` property in the first place.

Comment: its not working for me I editet my code at the bottom, maybe you understand now , I get also the error message " error of undefined

Answer (score 0):

> Why I get this message?

> Cannot read property 'error' of undefined

this because your `out` object does not have `result` parameter every time, and returns `undefined` at that time so you cant access to `out.result.error` because `out.result` is `undefined`

Solution

```js
if(out?.result?.error) {
    console.log('ERROR');
}
```

Comment: its not working for me I editet my code at the bottom, maybe you understand now , I get also the error message " error of undefined